# Keeping the information obtained in a $.ajax call's done(...) method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coding-style, scope

I'm getting the correct stuff in *done* but the assignment to a variable with an wider scope doesn't work. It worked for e.g. *$.each(...)* so I assumed, incorrectly, that it'd work here too.

```
var outee = null;
$.ajax({
  url: "http://...",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  ...
}).done(function (stuff) { 
  // works well
  displayThe(stuff);
  // works well (but targets probably a global outee)
  outee = stuff;
  displayThe(outee);
});
// fail due to outee being nada, nicht, zilch etc.
displayThe(outee);
```

How can I store *stuff* for usage **outside** the scope of the anonymous function in *done* method that obtained it?

Am I correct to assume that the assignment **inside** *done* refers to a global *outee*? One way to resolve my problem would be not to hide the global *outee* by the declaration n the method of a *var*-ed *outsee*, right? But that's a bad programming style to me. Comments?

Comment: It's not a scope problem. Assigning the value like you did is fine. The problem is that `displayThe(outee);` (in the last line) is called **before** the Ajax response was received, i.e. before the data as been set. Ajax is **asynchronous**. Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/. As long as you can ensure that the access to the global variable always occurs *after* the value was set, you are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right you are assigning to a global variable in your `.done`, There's nothing wrong in that, the problem is that you are trying to use that global variable before your ajax call is completed (*i.e before your `.done` is executed*).

That is because of asynchronous behavior or ajax.
One *bad* way to make it work is to make your ajax call synchronous with `async:false`

Comment: As you said, `async:false` is bad and even more so it does not work with JSONP (what the OP seems to use).

Comment: OP **is** JSONP'ing so he can't (and doesn't want to of badness considerations) to set it on asynchronous. Now that I think about it, I realize that what I want is an **asynchronous** call that is guaranteed to be **performed before** other stuff. I know, I know - I'm being sarcastic over my own brain-cheeze-cutting.